# Does Entity Framework 4 not support property automatic lazy loading for model-first entities?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-framework-4

All references that I find for lazy loading say it's possible but they all mention POCOs and that's it.  I am using EF4 with the model-first methodology.  In my model diagram I have a Project table and a UserObject table, with a 1 to many relationship between them.  However, in code, when I have a valid UserObject and I attempt to get the project performing: `Project prj = userobj.Project`.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work as it claims that UserObject.Project is null.

It seems like I have to explicitly load the Project object via calling UserObject.ProjectReference.Load() prior to calling .Project.  Is there any way for this to occur automatically when I access the .Project property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine.  Right click on the EDMX, click Properties, check that `Lazy loading enabled` is set for the EDMX.

Comment: I don't see a lazy loading option in any of the properties in the EDMX

Comment: Found it.  Apparently my domain model project was set for .net 3.5.  Setting it to 4.0 enabled this option!